# How to solve this (missing: CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) issue?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cmake, lua

I am trying to install Torch using [this thread](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_)

And when I tried run ./install.sh which installs LuaJIT, LuaRocks, and then uses LuaRocks (the Lua package manager) to install core packages like a torch, an NN and paths, as well as a few other packages.

I am getting this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message): Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found suitable version "8.0", minimum required is "6.5") Call Stack (most recent call first): /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) /home/htic/torch/install/share/cmake/torch/FindCUDA.cmake:1009 (find_package_handle_standard_args) CMakeLists.txt:7 (FIND_PACKAGE)  
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/htic/torch/extra/cutorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".  
Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

In bash file, I have tried:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CUDNN_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.6" export CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include"
```

and creating a symlink `/usr/local/cuda-8.0` as `/usr/local/cuda` but still, the error persists.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. A combination of the following things helped:

- installed CUDA 9.1 with deb package and ran

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
  ```

  which I had installed previously and which gave me CUDA 7.5
- ran

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```
- before trying again to run ./install.sh I ran "sudo ./clean.sh" in the torch directory

(I am using Linux Mint 18)